# Inviting user with personal account to collaborate on a organization repository

Tags: github, github-actions, repository

I want to collaborate with one more person who uses a personal account.

I want to create an organization and buy extra storage for my project that handles uassets and fbx files with git lfs.

My question is, my friend who uses a personal account and doesn't want to pay anything, is he going to be able to join the repository (organization) and push files over the 1 GB limitation of GitHub? I will be buying the extra storage and I ll be the code owner.

I got confused because when I went to upgrade my acc to organization it said per user and I thought that it might need everyone to have upgraded accounts to join an organization repository

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkl7S.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxtJD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GitHub, when you create an organization and buy extra storage for a repository that uses Git lfs, it's primarily the owner of the organization or repository who pays for the additional storage. Members of the organization, including ones with personal accounts, can collaborate on the repository without needing to pay for extra storage themselves.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).